# how to recursively delete directory starting with "xxxxx"?

Tags: visual-c++, directory

I need to delete Directories that are starting with particular String "user"and i need to delete all the sub-folders in the Directory too.
I used removedirectory which deletes directory only when it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Normally I would open a command window then cd to the directory you want to delete,
    Enter the command: "del /S /F *.* *" to delete all files and subdirectories.
    Backup to the parent directory: cd ..
    Remove the directory: rmdir "user*"

    Use "del/?" to see all the options for del.

    If you have to do this in c++, you can use the "system()" call.

    BTW: I did not test this just now, so no guarantee.
```